# "Eu indico a ele" ou "eu indico-lhe" existem diferenças no Brasil e em Portugal na sua utilização , são corretas as duas ali?

Tags: português-brasileiro, português-europeu, sintaxe, frases

"Eu indico a ele" ou "eu indico-lhe" existem diferenças no Brasil e em Portugal na sua utilização , são corretas as duas ali?

Vejo muitos Brasileiros utilizarem, eu indico a ela, exemplo nas novelas. é correto?

Comment: De acordo com Houaiss, "indicar a" como "eu indiquei ao João um advogado que sempre excele em seu trabalho" é correto e esse "a" indica objeto indireto, então, sim: podes falar "eu lhe indiquei um péssimo advogado". Eu sou brasileiro e uso mais "para" em vez de "a" e falo bastante "eu vou te indicar o meu dentista". Vale lembrar que "indiquei para o ventilador com a minha mão" quer dizer "indiquei em direção ao ventilador com a minha mão", então, nem toda preposição indica objeto direto ou indireto, ou seja, "o ventilador, eu lhe indiquei com a minha mão" soa mal, mesmo não estando errado.

Comment: Faz tempo que os brasileiros decideram de não usar pronomes COD e COI. Vi ela na rua. Em vez de: A vi na rua. Na minha opinião, é pena. Sobre tudo, essa de ter te misturado com terçera pessoa.

Answer (score 1):

Como falante brasileiro da região de São Paulo, o que soa mais natural para mim é:

- Eu indiquei (=recomendei) o livro para ele.
- Eu indiquei (=apontei) o caminho para ele.

Na linguagem não formal, 'pra' no lugar de 'para'.

Eu nunca escutei 'indicar-lhe' no Brasil, talvez seja usado em situações muito formais.

Comment: Bom dia. A fonetica por vezes nao corresponde à resposta correta.

Comment: Pois é, por o pronomes COI e COD estão infelizmente desaparecendo no Brasil, com algumas excepções.

Answer (score -1):

as duas são corretas porém usadas em circunstâncias diferentes.

Comment: Bom dia. É  importante  justificar e fundamentar as respostas.